# How to configure Ingress backend to work exclusively with TLSv1.3

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have an ingress (nginx) that proxies to an application exposing 8443 (SSL) with a self-signed certificate. It works all fine in http but in https I get the following error:

```
2022/10/31 18:04:28 [error] 39#39: *1855 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1409442E:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert protocol version:SSL alert number 70) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /web-service/ HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://10.2.1.37:8443/web-service/", host: "localhost:8443"
```

After a little bit of research I established that my web-service is only supporting:

```
"TLSv1.3" and "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256:TLS_AE"
```

I curled in and indeed if I use anything else than explicitly TLSv1.3 I get a similar error. I also force the web service to downgrade to TLSv1.2 and it works but obviously that's not great.

Is there a way to configure the ingress nginx backend configuration to only use TLSv1.3 and these protocols in the ingress itself.

Something like `ssl_protocols TLSv1.3;` but as an annotation at the backend level? I tried a snippet but it does not seem to be applied at the right level.

Here is my current code:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-world-ingress2
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-client: "off"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /web-service/$1
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /web-service/(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-web-service
            port:
              number: 8443
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need to add configMap to change the default behavior.

See at the end of following link:

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/#default-tls-version-and-ciphers

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately this does not change the backend but the frontend of the ingress. This helps to accept whatever protocols as input to the ingress. Not to force the backend proxy over a specific version of TLS/cipher

Answer (score 0):

So apparently there is no solution at the writing this but to downgrade the backend to TLS v1.2. See open ticket https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/8257